# HTTP Requests before Electron application show any window

Tags: json, spring-boot, electron, restful-url

I would like to make some requests for a RESTful API before displaying any window of my application. Does anyone knows a good way to do this? Would anyone has an example?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can add those API calls in `main.js` file where window creation code also resides.

```
app.on('ready', function () {
  //make api calls

  var request = require('request');
  request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred 
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received 
      console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage. 

      // Create the browser window.
      mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1000, height: 625 });

  });     

  ...    
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. But how do you create REST API in electron? Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `request` npm module and I have updated my answer for same.